# Свой тип переменной в замыкании маршрута Laravel

Tags: laravel, замыкания, маршрут

В маршрутизации в laravel для примера часто можно встретить такой код:

```
use .../Post;
use .../User;
Route::get("/user/{user}/post/{post}",function (User $user, Post $post){

   return ...

})
```

Как я понимаю,  в функцию замыкания уже передаются  переменные в виде объектов.
Что и  где нужно зарегистрировать, чтобы добиться такого эффекта? Как мне передать в функцию замыкания объект на основе собственного класса?(например , Product $product?)

Comment: Если я Вас верно понял, то [Parameters & Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-and-dependency-injection). Но в данном случае (в Вашем примере), передается то что соответствует обязательным параметрам роута, `/user/{user}/post/{post}` и имеете соответственно `function (User $user, Post $post)`.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш класс - это Eloquent модель, то используйте [настройку ключа](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key) (ссылка на раздел сломалась у них, ищите `Customizing The Key`).

Вы всегда можете реализовать собственную логику через [Route::bind](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic).

И конечно же, вы всегда можете использовать [внедрение зависимостей](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container).

Читайте документацию, у Laravel она отличная.